# hide report manager Home, My Subscriptions | Site Settings | Help links by default when passing report URL to users

Tags: asp.net, webbrowser-control, reporting-services

I have an SSRS remote report whose URL i want to give to intranet users. But the report is displayed in report manager in internet explorer, users can see the **Home, My Subscriptions | Site Settings | Help** links at the top of the report.

So if a user clicks on the Home link, they might get access to the other reports they are not supposed to. Is there a way of formating the url such that those links that appear above the report in report manager are hidden by default when the report is vied from the that formated link?

Comment: if i click full screen arrows on the report toolbar in report manager, the links i mention above are hidden, i want 'similar' behavior by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from another thread here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/64d8312a-e37b-4b94-8d24-06e8e980c817